# UIAlertView wont delegate

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit

I'm try to get from an UIAlertView the Content with following:

```
UIAlertView *loginView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Login"
                                                    message:@"Please enter user and pass"
                                                   delegate:self
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Abort"
                                          otherButtonTitles:@"Login", nil];
[loginView setAlertViewStyle:UIAlertViewStyleLoginAndPasswordInput];
[loginView show];
```

and then

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex == 1)
    {
        UITextField *username = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0];
        NSLog(@"username: %@", username.text);

        UITextField *password = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:1];
        NSLog(@"password: %@", password.text);

    }
}
```

in my .h File

```
@interface loginTest :  UIViewController <UIAlertViewDelegate>
```

what is wrong here?

Comment: What exactly doesn't work?

Comment: Im not able to get from the textFields a Value.

Comment: Does your delegate method fire? Are you pressing the correct button (index == 1)?

Comment: Nope, tested manually and added NSLog before if (buttionIndex == 1)

Comment: This code is working fine for me. Is the console printing nothing at all, or just "username:" and "password:"?

Comment: Can you share a sample project that demonstrates the issue? It also seems correct to me.

Comment: phew... thats weird. If im execute the code on "ViewController.m" with [self blub] it works. But if im use my abc.h and abc.m File and call in viewDidLoad [[abc alloc] init] and in the abc.m 
-(void)init{
[self alert]
}

Its not working

As a beginner, i think the Problem is the delegate.

Comment: pseudo code is great and all, but objc loves very descriptive class and variable names :) classes are always capitalized as well. think of your fellow coders in the future who will be reading this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your question is missing some important details that are causing the issue, so answer comes from speculating on the last comment you made. You need to have all your view controllers implement the alert view delegate that will be presenting a `UIAlertView`. It sounds like you implement the delegate in `ViewController`, but not in `abc`. To further explain, here's an explanation in code.

Lets say you have `ViewControllerA` and `ViewControllerB`. In `ViewControllerA.h`:

```
@interface ViewControllerA : UIViewController <UIAlertViewDelegate>
```

And in `ViewControllerB.h`:

```
@interface ViewControllerB : UIViewController <UIAlertViewDelegate>
```

Then in both `ViewControllerA.m` and `ViewControllerB.m`, you need to implement:

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex == 1)
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

When you display a `UIAlertView` and set the delegate to `self`, `self` refers to the view controller that you are currently in. If only one of your view controllers implement the delegate methods, and a different view controller displays the alert, the alert reports back to the view controller that presented it (which doesn't implement the delegate), therefore it doesn't do anything when it's done. I hope this answers your question.