# import and UIAlertView

Tags: ios, objective-c

depending on my other Question: [UIAlertView wont delegate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27965885/uialertview-wont-delegate)

I got today to a new Problem, currently im learning Objective-C and sorry if this Question is too simple or stupid. :-)

Ok, im gonna create a Single View Application, then im gonna create a new Cocoa Touch Class with following Content:

### ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIAlertViewDelegate>


@end
```

### ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "logon.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    logon *lf = [[logon alloc] init];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

### logon.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface logon :  UIView <UIAlertViewDelegate>

-(id)init;
-(void)showLoginForm;

@end
```

### logon.m

```
#import "logon.h"

@implementation logon

-(id)init{
    [self showLoginForm];
    return @"test";
}

-(void)showLoginForm{

    UIAlertView *loginView = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                              initWithTitle:@"Login"
                              message:@"Please enter your Credentials"
                              delegate: self
                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Abort"
                              otherButtonTitles:@"Login", nil];
    [loginView setAlertViewStyle:UIAlertViewStyleLoginAndPasswordInput];
    [loginView show];
}

-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
    if (buttonIndex == 1){
        UITextField *username = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0];
        UITextField *password = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:1];
        NSLog(@"user %@ and pass %@", username, password);
        // ^^^^^^^ is empty
    }
}

@end
```

So, i have absolutely no idea, what im doing wrong here. The UIAlertView appears but after typing something into, my alertView wont get called.

Comment: r u get the result in NSLog(@"user %@ and pass %@", username, password);

Comment: you should try username.text and password.text for getting value. as user name and password is a UITextField.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I don't see why LoginForm is a `UIView`. Besides that, your `-init` is completely wrong, try this:

```
- (id)init {
    if ((self = [super init])) {

    }
    return self;
}
```

It also makes more sense to call `showLoginForm` from your controller and to not name it `logon`, classes always start with an uppercase letter:

```
LoginForm *form = [[LoginForm alloc] init];
[form showLoginForm];
```

Lastly, you have to retain your `LoginForm` because if you don't, the Os frees its memory and you won't receive delegate calls (I am surprised that you don't get a SEGFAULT though).

Create a new property in your view controller:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) LoginForm *form;
```

And use this code when you want to show the alert view:

```
_form = [[LoginForm alloc] init];
[_form showLoginForm];
```

Comment: Thanks Tim, you're right now it works as wanted. Im gonna check out the Basics again with init and properties.

Answer (score -1):

have you tried to output the textFields Content?

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
    if (buttonIndex == 1){
        UITextField *username = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0];
        UITextField *password = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:1];
        NSLog(@"user %@ and pass %@", username.text, password.text);
        // ^^^^^^^ is empty
    }
}
```

Btw... Why aren't you displaying your AlertView direct in your ViewController?

Comment: But it wasnt not called before i changed as Tim wrote.